# Mouse/Camera suddenly jerking to one side in game, not a hardware issue

Tags: windows-10, windows-8, mouse, gaming

I've been trying to figure out what has been causing this. I recently upgraded from an old win 7 laptop to a win 10 one, and since then, a particular game that I play (DDO) has had the camera suddenly jerking to one side at random intervals. There is no consistent pattern that I can find.

Video of the bug in action : https://streamable.com/fbxuj

While facing the wall, I start strafing right, and suddenly the camera jerks to the right.

This is not a mouse hardware issue, a usb port issue, a touchpad issue, etc...it only happens in this one game (for me at least) and it also happens for many other players.

Support has no idea what causes this, and people have reported it as far back as 2012.

I did a lot of searching and I found similar issues in other games like WOW...most of the posts I found were people upgrading to win 10 and then finding that their camera would suddenly jerk to one side or keep "spinning".

Quite a few of the posts blamed Microsoft for a win 8 or the win 10 fall creators update that changed the way they handled mouse drivers.

I found this hotfix for win 8 on the Microsoft site : https://support.microsoft.com/en-au/help/2908279/mouse-pointer-stutters-or-freezes-when-you-play-certain-games-in-windo.

Obviously cant install it as I am using win 10, but I tried the manual method (editing the registry) and it made no difference.

Does anyone have any suggestions on how to troubleshoot or identify what is causing this? Game support has no idea, and it definately isnt a hardware issue on my end. Its something to do with the way the game handles mouse input as far as I can tell.

Comment: If its to do with the game handling input, then it should happen with all mice used. If you try with multiple different mice, does the issue persist? If it does, then you might not be able to resolve it until a patch is released for Windows or the game. If its just the one mouse doing it, then it could be the driver for that particular mouse (or possible other software, like Logitech macro software for example) thats causing a corrupt interface between the game and the driver. Once you have narrowed it down to a root cause, you can begin to find possible workarounds for it.

Comment: Is your touch pad enabled by chance? Maybe try disabling it and make sure it's not your hand that is occasionally registering and making it jump.

Comment: @QuickishFM It happens with all mice, multiple people have tested this. Its definately a game issue. Just trying to narrow down what the issue could be as the game support appears to have no idea.

Comment: @DrZoo Definately not a touchpad issue, as mine is disabled and others have reported that it happens for their desktops as well.